# PHP condition with HTML/PHP putput

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I running WordPress site and I want to show something only if post format is quote. I have following code but it give fatal error:

```
<?php if ( 'quote' == get_post_format() ) {
    
print '<blockquote>
<font size = "5"><?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, '1QUOTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE', true);
wp_reset_query();
?></font>
  <span class="author"><i><a href="<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, '3RLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL', true);
wp_reset_query();
?>"><?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, '2AUTORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR', true);
wp_reset_query();
?></a></i></span>
</blockquote>';

} ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add what the error message says to the question as it helps understand the problem.

Comment: Wrong syntax in your php. You had another php open tag `<?php` inside a php open tag. So you are closing php when printing a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your code. Try simplifying your code as follows:

```
<?php 
if ( 'quote' == get_post_format() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
?>

<blockquote>
    <font size = "5">
    <?php 
        echo get_post_meta($postid, '1QUOTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE', true);
    ?>
    </font>

    <span class="author">
        <i>
            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($postid, '3RLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL', true);?>">
                <?php
                    echo get_post_meta($postid, '2AUTORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR', true);
                ?>
            </a>
        </i>
    </span>
</blockquote>
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

If you still get the Fatal error, share the error with us. It will help point us in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your contributions are welcome, but this question is off-topic as it's just a syntax error. Answering off-topic questions is against the guidelines because it just encourages more :) Take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), in particular "answer well-asked questions" for your future answers. Also, just be aware that answers to off-topic questions can be down-voted even if the answer is good. Your effort is better used for on-topic questions that are useful to all users (and therefore more likely to get up votes) :)

Comment: He wouldn't have been able to add a comment probably.